# Perspective projection not working in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'was displaying a cube in opengl. Here is my file for vertex shader

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

uniform vec3 offset;
uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 cameraPos = position + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, offset.z, 0.0);

    //gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * cameraPos;
    gl_Position.xy = cameraPos.xy;
    gl_Position.z = cameraPos.z*2.0f + 3.0f;
    gl_Position.w = -cameraPos.z;

    float tmp = gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w;
    theColor = color;

}
```

[image: ret]

The result is weird.It seems that the five faces other than the front face are showed, which should all be disappeared.The back face is now in front of the front face.Here is the two triangles for the front face:

```
0.25f,  0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
0.25f, -0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f,  0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

 0.25f, -0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f, -0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f,  0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
```

the data for the back face:

```
0.25f,  0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f,  0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
0.25f, -0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,

0.25f, -0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f,  0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
-0.25f, -0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f,
```

I choose -1.0f and 3.0f for the near and far plane respectively,so 
 (n + f) / (f - n) = 2.0f and 
(2 * n * f) / (f - n) = 3.0f.Why the result is such weird?

Comment: 1) And what did you choose for the rest of the parameters? Near and far are not the only parameters a perspective projection has. 2) If you see back-faces in front: Have you enabled depth-testing?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/oyjw/gl-learning/blob/master/gl/%E6%BA%90.cpp)Here is the project.And I think I only have the near and far parameters.I just leave the x and y coordinates as they are so that when they are divided by w they are in the [-1,1] range.After some computation I found that 0.25f,  0.25f, -1.0f, 1.0f -> 0.25 0.25 1 1 and 0.25f,  0.25f, -3.0f, 1.0f, ->0.083 0.083 -1 1

Comment: I don't enable depth-testing.

Comment: Setting element [0][0] and [1][1] of the matrix to 1 gives you a really strange field-of-view. Since [1][1] is for example defined as `cot(fov/2)` leads to a fov of PI which means 180° opening angle for your camera. With this projection, the cube looks exactly as it should look like. ([Source](https://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/gluPerspective))

Comment: To get the depth-order problem solved enable depth-testing.

Comment: You might want to consider using a library like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net) to do the tedious work for you.

Comment: @BDL Thanks for your comment.The fact that I didn't enable depth-testing is what I did wrong.

Answer (score -1):

After some test,I get the correct image.

[image: ret]

I know what did I do wrong now.

First, the window I created didn't have a depth buffer and I did't enable the depth test.As the data of the five faces other than the front face was loaded after the front face, they were all be drawn.

Second, (n + f) / (f - n) and  (2 * n * f) / (f - n) should change to (n + f) / (f - n) and  (2 * n * f) / (f - n) .

```
Why the negations? OpenGL wants to present to the programmer a  
right-handed coordinate system before projection and left-handed 
coordinate system after projection.
```

That's the information I found.The larger z values will finally become smaller z value in the window space, which is exactly the depth value.
And as the default value for glDepthFunc is GL_LESS, the front face will show before the other faces.